If you happen to daven with a minyan that say tachanun when you normally wouldn't, do you need to say it with them?
I'm guessing you must respond to va'yikra in any case but I'm not sure about the rest.

Why wouldn't you normally say tachanun? And why are they saying?
These details matter

the easiest common example would be someone not saying it for Independence Day or Jerusalem day in Israel in a minyan that doesn't consider these days special to Jewish history. Another example would be some chosid who has some special tzadik yortzeit while the minyan has no idea about it (or doesn't care about it)

@redolfovic: in a minyan that doesn't consider these days special to Jewish history - alternatively, a minyan that says tachanun despite the day being special to Jewish History.

@chortkov2  mincha on erev pesach sheini would be a good example, the mishna berura brings a machlokes  if tachnun is to be said. Some kehilos are more stringent about this than others

The Talmud (Megilla 22b) tells us of certain rabbis who didn't fall on their face in prayer even though the rest of the congregation did.

If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.

I have only been a registered user of Mi Yodeya since April 2024 and I have already seen many variants of this question, for example:
Saying kaddish when davening in a minyan that isn't your nusach
Which tefilot you say when your minhag differs from that of the shoul your praying in?
Should I follow the congregation if their view on prayers for Yom Ha'Atzma'ut is different than mine?
Which Tachanun should I say when davening in a minyan with a different Nusach?
As I understand it, the general rule (and a common sense solution) is that for quiet parts of the davening, you can follow your own nusach/custom or follow the nusach/custom of the minyan. For the parts of the davening that are said aloud, you should follow the nusach/custom of the minyan.
The answer to the OP's question appears to be that given by Rabbi David Lau which is part of the answer to Which Tachanun should I say when davening in a minyan with a different Nusach? [emphasis added]
Rabbi David Lau says that one who Daven's Ashkenaz, and finds himself in a Sefard Minyan should say his Ashkenaz Tachanun, however when the Chazzan says Vayavor you should say the 13 Midos with the congregation.

אתה אומר את הנוסח שלך, אבל כשהחזן מכריז ויעבור, אתה אומר עם הציבור
את י``ג מידות


If you like my answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.
